# Is Hoeffding's bound tight in any way?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

The inequality:
$$\Pr(\overline X - \mathrm{E}[\overline X] \geq t) \leq \exp \left( - \frac{2n^2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i - a_i)^2} \right) $$

Is this bound (or any other form of hoeffding) tight in any sense? e.g. does there exist a distribution for which the bound is no more than a constant multiple of the true probability for every $n$?

Answer (score 4):

Because it fully answers the question, I will quote almost verbatim Theorem 7.3.1
from Matoušek, Jiří, and Jan Vondrák. "The probabilistic method." *Lecture Notes, Department of Applied Mathematics, Charles University, Prague (2001).* downloadable as of today at [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15850/handouts/matousek-vondrak-prob-ln.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E15850/handouts/matousek-vondrak-prob-ln.pdf)

**7.3.1 Theorem.** Let $S$ be a sum of i.i.d. $[0,1]$-valued random variables, and assume $\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(S)} \ge 200$. Then, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that, for all $t\in\big[0,\operatorname{Var}(S)/100\big]$, we have
$$ \mathbb{P}\big(S\ge \mathbb{E}[S] + t\big)\ge c \exp\bigg(-\frac{t^2}{3\operatorname{Var}(S)}\bigg).$$
In particular if $S=X_1+\dots+X_n$ for i.i.d. $X_i$, then for all $t\in \big[0,n\operatorname{Var}(X_1)/100\big]$
$$ \mathbb{P}\big(S\ge \mathbb{E}[S] + t\big)\ge c \exp\bigg(-\frac{t^2n}{3\operatorname{Var}(X_1)}\bigg)$$
Proposition 7.3.2 in the same reference has explicit values for $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one such case is when all the random variables are uniform in $[0,1]$. The sum of uniform random variables has the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) and its tail bound matches the one given by Hoeffding's inequality. See Corollary 5 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.09006.pdf).  Also see [Bernstein's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory)) which is a generalization of Hoeffding.